# Neural network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have trained xor neural network in MATLAB and got these weights:

```
iw: [-2.162 2.1706; 2.1565 -2.1688]

lw: [-3.9174 -3.9183]

b{1} [2.001; 2.0033]

b{2} [3.8093]
```

Just from curiosity I have tried to write MATLAB code which computes the output of this network (two neurons in the hidden layer, and one in the output, TANSIG activation function).

Code that I got:

```
l1w = [-2.162 2.1706; 2.1565 -2.1688];
l2w = [-3.9174 -3.9183];
b1w = [2.001 2.0033];
b2w = [3.8093];

input = [1, 0];

out1 = tansig (input(1)*l1w(1,1) + input(2)*l1w(1,2) + b1w(1));
out2 = tansig (input(1)*l1w(2,1) + input(2)*l1w(2,2) + b1w(2));
out3 = tansig (out1*l2w(1) + out2*l2w(2) + b2w(1))
```

The problem is when input is lets say [1,1], it outputs **-0.9989**, when [0,1] **0.4902**. While simulating network generated with MATLAB outputs adequately are **0.00055875** and **0.99943**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why dont you post the actual code you used to build and train the network?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a simple example of an XOR network. I used `newpr`, which defaults  to `tansig` transfer function for both hidden and output layers.

```
input = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1];               %# each column is an input vector
ouputActual = [0 1 1 0];

net = newpr(input, ouputActual, 2);       %# 1 hidden layer with 2 neurons
net.divideFcn = '';                       %# use the entire input for training

net = init(net);                          %# initialize net
net = train(net, input, ouputActual);     %# train
outputPredicted = sim(net, input);        %# predict
```

then we check the result by computing the output ourselves. The important thing to remember is that by default, inputs/outputs are **scaled** to the [-1,1] range:

```
scaledIn = (2*input - 1);           %# from [0,1] to [-1,1]
for i=1:size(input,2)
    in = scaledIn(:,i);             %# i-th input vector
    hidden(1) = tansig( net.IW{1}(1,1)*in(1) + net.IW{1}(1,2)*in(2) + net.b{1}(1) );
    hidden(2) = tansig( net.IW{1}(2,1)*in(1) + net.IW{1}(2,2)*in(2) + net.b{1}(2) );
    out(i) = tansig( hidden(1)*net.LW{2,1}(1) + hidden(2)*net.LW{2,1}(2) + net.b{2} );
end
scaledOut = (out+1)/2;              %# from [-1,1] to [0,1]
```

or more efficiently expressed as matrix product in one line:

```
scaledIn = (2*input - 1);           %# from [0,1] to [-1,1]
out = tansig( net.LW{2,1} * tansig( net.IW{1}*scaledIn + repmat(net.b{1},1,size(input,2)) ) + repmat(net.b{2},1,size(input,2)) );
scaledOut = (1 + out)/2;            %# from [-1,1] to [0,1]
```

Comment: Excellent. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You usually don't use a sigmoid on your output layer--are you sure you should have the tansig on out3?  And are you sure you are looking at the weights of the appropriately trained network?  It looks like you've got a network trained to do XOR on [1,1] [1,-1] [-1,1] and [-1,-1], with +1 meaning "xor" and -1 meaning "same".

Comment: Then how do you normalize your output if you don't use Sigmoid in the output layer? Furthermore how do you measure error if your output is not normalized?

Comment: For a classifier, you pick the output with the highest value (or toggle at the 50% point) to make your decision.  You don't need the nonlinearity.  In this case it's _okay_ to do it, but it doesn't really add much.

Comment: the problem of using a linear function in the output layer becomes apparent when you want to get posterior probabilities of each class in addition to the classifications..

Comment: @Amro: Fair enough.  If you want them to be forced into the range (0,1), then yes, you should use `1/(1+exp(-y))`; you get approximate probabilities either way but you might exceed 1 (or fall below 0) if you just treat it as a function approximation.  Whether that is a problem depends on the application.